# Change datatype from float32 to float64 in a tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to change the data type of the pos_ds numerical features from float32 to float 64 but not able to find the right way of how to do so. Any suggestions. I am using tensorflow 2.2.

```
def make_ds(features, labels):
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))#.cache()
    ds = ds.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).repeat()
    return ds

neg_ds = make_ds(neg_features, neg_labels)
pos_ds = make_ds(pos_features, pos_labels)

for features, label in pos_ds.take(1):
    print("Features:\n", features.values())
    print()
    print("Label: ", label.numpy())
```

Output:

```
Features:
dict_values([<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=4.89784>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=4.727388>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=4.6051702>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=4.727388>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=4.804021>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=4.882802>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=4.912655>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'nan'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'nan'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'nan'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'0.0'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'nan'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'NO_DCLRD_URL'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'nan'>])
Label: 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You could convert the features & pos_labels to a tensor first before calling `from_tensor_slices`:

```
features = np.zeros(2, dtype=np.float32)
features = tf.convert_to_tensor(features,dtype=tf.float64)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([features])
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but the features data has mixed datatypes. Certain columns are string data type and others are float.

Comment: Then I ask you kindly to specify your question. You asked for a conversion from float32 to float64. Please post a small data example, and specify what exactly you want to achieve